# Flutter: Keep a Row alive when Navigation.push happens

Tags: flutter, navigation, transition, tabbar, appbar

Using Flutter,

I would like to keep a bottom-bar (i.e. screen-wide row of let's say 40 pixel height) always on top of my screen - no matter what Navigation.push() transitions happen in the rest of the app. Most importantly, this bottom-bar shall always stay on top of the navigation-shadows (or page-border).

Is this possible in Flutter ? And if yes, how ??

Answer (score 0):

One trick that I've found is to use ["Hero"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be9UH1kXFDw)

Using Hero, I can "heroefy" my desired bottom-bar (i.e. screen-wide row) in Screen-Nr1 and "hereofy" it with the very same dimensions in Screen-Nr2. In both screens, I placed this bottom-bar into a Container that I was able to get wrapped around by Hero.

The important part was to keep the dimensions of the two Hero-child-Containers in Screen1 and 2 identical. This has the nice effect that the Transition-shaddows are behind the "bottom-bar"-Containers and that is exactly what I need !